# How does catdog reproduce?

Tags: character, catdog

In the episode where they go to the future there is a tiny catdog, now my question is how does catdog reproduce? I know that it’s a cartoon and all,but do they have reproductive organs? I just needed a authorial answer at this time. Sorry if I’ve been confusing about it.

Comment: i would think they would since Dog can mark his territory. it's been a while but i remember one episode where he marks a hydrant and the next time he passes he smells someone else has marked it and keeps cat back as he waits for whoever marked his hydrant (i think it was a tiny poodle who's with the fire department). since dogs urinate with the same organ used for production i would suspect this assuming that Dog urinates to mark his territory

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Through the magic of being a kids cartoon.

Kids programs (for obvious reasons) don't go into the mechanics of conception (that would be weird, and wrong, and lead to complaints from concerned parents everywhere).  It's fair to assume that kissy-kissy leads to babies within the confines of a loving environment.

Even kids know that cartoons aren't really indicative of real life.